# best image processing library for java

Tags: java, image-processing, webcam

could you please suggest the best image processing library for pure Java environment?

I'll need to do webcam capture, and object detection in real time.
Or if you have any similar projects doing this it will be great. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Catalano Framework](https://code.google.com/p/catalano-framework/) is the best lib in image processing for java. It works in Android too with the same code.
Example:

```
FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap("c:\\yourImage.bmp");

fb.toGrayscale();

Threshold t = new Threshold(120);
t.applyInPlace(fb);

// Your objects.
BlobDetection bd = new BlobDetection();
ArrayList<Blob> blobs = bd.ProcessImage(fb);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a wrapper for openCV for Java at http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

That's the best for doing object detection and such. Anyway you must first grab images and for that you can use JMF.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what about webcam capture? Is opencv providing all necessary to do that?

Comment: For image processing OpenCV and for webcam capturing JMF. JMF is a pain in the ass in my opinion but I think it's the only viable alternative out there.

Comment: **OpenCV** supports Webcam capture, so You can go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look in [JAI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/index.html) and [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html).

Comment: JMF is not only not supported (for a long time now), but AFAIU all things to do with webcams require the [Performance Pack](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) JMF which includes natives and is not available for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

[Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) provides algorithms for image and video processing, including object tracking.